# Is there a 64-bit build of IIS express 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-express

The documentation at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1010/iis-75-express-readme/
says that:

> Both 32-bit and 64-bit systems are supported, however only a 32-bit build of IIS 7.5 Express exists.

Why is this limitation there? are there any plans to get a 64-bit build?

I'm getting a lot of OOME using the 32-bit express on my test machine ... how were are supposed to simulate running on the real IIS, if the test server is so limited ...

Comment: The docs are quite clear. Any answer would only be speculative.

Comment: Might push the iis-express team to produce the much needed 64-bit build.

Comment: What's wrong with real IIS? I can't think why you'd need to simulate something that already exists. Does it not run on your Windows version?

Comment: @spender ... nothing is wrong with the real IIS ... why did microsoft created an express edition ? To use it for development, right? 
And in development you want to simulate everything ... makes sense ?

Comment: I use full IIS for development. It's easy and you know that it's going to work in production. I worry that using subtly different product for dev might sting me later.

Comment: I like the full IIS, but using it requires to launch VS in admin mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIS Express 8.0 has 64-bit support. At the time of writing it's an RC.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679

Comment: Wonderful news ... at last something helpful

Comment: Dead link (as of 2012-09-05). I've posted a link to the download.

Comment: Thanks, I've also updated my link to make it easier to find the right link.

Comment: I've fixed the link to the latest version

Answer (score 4):

It's now here iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi -

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679

Answer (score 4):

This option is now part of Vs 2013 / 2015:

> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the
>   64 bit version of IIS Express

Answer (score 3):

As of the date of this answer, there is no 64-bit build for IIS express. We all hope this changes sometime soon in the future.